# Configuring nagios email notification using sSMTP on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email, nagios

I have configured nagios email notification and followed following steps:

**sSMTP configuration:**

```
#apt-get install ssmtp  #vi /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
root=sender.email@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=
hostname=mycomputerName
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthMethod=LOGIN
AuthUser=sender.email@gmail.com
AuthPass=sender.email.password
FromLineOverride=YES
#chmod 640 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

**Nagios Configuration:**

```
#vi /etc/nagios3/conf.d/localhost_nagios2.cfg
define host{
          use                     generic-host            ; Name of host template to use
          host_name               localhost
          alias                   localhost
          address                 x.x.x.187
          check_command           check-host-alive
          max_check_attempts      10
          notification_interval   120
         notification_period     24x7
          notification_options    d,r
          contact_groups  admins
  }


 #vi /etc/nagios3/conf.d/timeperiods_nagios2.cfg
 define timeperiod{
         timeperiod_name 24x7
         alias           24 Hours A Day, 7 Days A Week
        sunday          00:00-24:00
         monday          00:00-24:00
         tuesday         00:00-24:00
         wednesday       00:00-24:00
         thursday        00:00-24:00
         friday          00:00-24:00
         saturday        00:00-24:00
 }

 #vi /etc/nagios3/conf.d/contacts_nagios2.cfg
 define contact{
         contact_name                    localhost
         alias                           localhost 
         service_notification_period     24x7
         host_notification_period        24x7
         service_notification_options    w,u,c,r
         host_notification_options       d,r
         service_notification_commands   notify-by-email
         host_notification_commands      host-notify-by-email
         email                           receive.mail@gmail.com
 }
 define contactgroup{
         contactgroup_name       admins
         alias                   Nagios Administrators
         members                 localhost
 }

 #vi /etc/nagios3/conf.d/services_nagios2.cfg
 define service{
         use                             generic-service         
         host_name                       localhost
         service_description             SSH
         is_volatile                     0
         check_period                    24x7
         max_check_attempts              4
         normal_check_interval           5
         retry_check_interval            1
         contact_groups                  admins
         notification_interval           960
         notification_period             24x7
         check_command                   check_ssh
  }
```

**notify-by-email command:**

```
define command{
        command_name    notify-by-email
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios @VERSION@ *****\n \nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$OUTPUT$" | @MAIL_PROG@ -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ alert - $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
}
```

After configuring nagios I have restarted SSH but it does not send email notification.

**New**

**'notify-host-by-email' command definition**

```
define command{
        command_name    notify-host-by-email
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
        }
```

**'notify-service-by-email' command definition**

```
define command{
        command_name    notify-service-by-email
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
        }
```

Comment: What does `notify-by-email` definition look like? How do you test the email notification?

Comment: define command{

        command_name    notify-by-email

        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios @VERSION@ *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$OUTPUT$" | @MAIL_PROG@ -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ alert - $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
        }

Comment: Maybe sshd restart too fast. Go to Web UI -> Services -> SSH -> Send custom service notification to see what happens.

Comment: @quanta-> it shows "Sorry, but Nagios is currently not checking for external commands, so your command will not be committed!"

Comment: Edit `nagios.cfg` and change `check_external_commands=0` to `check_external_commands=1`, restart Nagios and try again.

Comment: I have done it and it showed error message(Could not stat() command file '/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd'!nfiguring open ssh on ubuntu) . I executed following command---$ sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add nagios www-data 2710 /var/lib/nagios3/rw
----$ sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add nagios nagios 751 /var/lib/nagios3. then followed this (Services -> SSH -> Send custom service notification) step and it shows successful message(Your command request was successfully submitted to Nagios for processing) but does not send email.

Comment: UI->Services->SSH bottom of the the page it shows following Service Commennts: "Notifications for this service are being suppressed because it was detected as having been flapping between different states (24.2% change >= 20.0% threshold). When the service state stabilizes and the flapping stops, notifications will be re-enabled."

Comment: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/flapping.html

Comment: I have set "flap_detection_enabled=0" in service. Still it does not send mail.

Comment: `nagios.log` and/or `nagios.debug`?

Comment: I checked nagios.log, bottom of the log it shows following warning message ([1344498571] Warning: Attempting to execute the command "/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios @VERSION@ *****\n\nNotification Type: PROBLEM\n\nService: SSH\nHost: localhost\nAddress: 192.168.1.176\nState: CRITICAL\n\nDate/Time: Thu Aug 9 13:49:31 BDT 2012\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$OUTPUT$" | @MAIL_PROG@ -s "** PROBLEM alert - localhost/SSH is CRITICAL **" khalid.xxxx@gmail.com" resulted in a return code of 127.  Make sure the script or binary you are trying to execute actually exists...
)

Comment: What is `@MAIL_PROG@`? Is that redacted?

Comment: I have changed command and checked nagios.log. Now it shows following message and does not send mail.

Finished daemonizing... (New PID=3131)
[1344567945] HOST ALERT: localhost;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.03 ms
[1344567945] HOST NOTIFICATION: localhost;localhost;UP;notify-host-by-email;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.03 ms
[1344568010] EXTERNAL COMMAND: SEND_CUSTOM_SVC_NOTIFICATION;localhost;SSH;0;nagiosadmin;aa
[1344568010] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: localhost;localhost;SSH;CUSTOM (CRITICAL);notify-service-by-email;CRITICAL - Socket timeout after 10 seconds;nagiosadmin;aa

Comment: What does it (`notify-by-email`) look like now?

Comment: notify-by-email has been replaced by notify-service-by-email and host-notify-by-email has been replaced by notify-host-by-email

Comment: Take a look at the `/var/log/maillog`.

Comment: /var/log/mail.log
Aug 10 10:26:54 khalid-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 sSMTP[5532]: /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf not found
Aug 10 10:26:54 khalid-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 sSMTP[5532]: Unable to locate mailhub
Aug 10 10:26:54 khalid-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 sSMTP[5532]: Cannot open mailhub:25

Comment: `ls -l /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`?

Comment: -rw-r----- 1 root mail 682 Aug  9 11:23 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you see the below line in the `/var/log/maillog`:

```
sSMTP[5532]: /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf not found
```

although it exists:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root mail 682 Aug 9 11:23 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

I suspect that you haven't add the `nagios` user to the `mail` group. Do it by following command:

```
# usermod -a -G mail nagios
```

and try again.

Comment: It works now. Thank you quanta....thank you very very much...